# Angular7 route redirect user

Tags: angular, angular-router

If a user logs in, it automatically redirects to the `route: ''` and I have the token stored in localStorage.

However, if a logged in user manually types in the url `route: /login` he should be routed in the `route: ''` and that is what I want to achieve.

What I did was to add a validation in my `OnInit()` inside my `LoginComponent` and it's working. But how can I achieve this in my AuthGuard? I am thinking of getting the requested route if `route: /login` and navigate to `route: ''` if already logged in.

Route:

```
{ path: '', component: PostListComponent },
{ path: 'create', component: PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'edit/:postId', component: PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
```

AuthGuard:

```
const currentRoute = route.url[0].path;
const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();

if (!isAuth) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}

if (currentRoute === '/login') {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}

console.log(currentRoute);
return isAuth;
```

LoginComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
 const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
 if (isAuth) {
   this.router.navigate(['/']);
 }
}
```

UPDATE: I updated my AuthGuard to check the current route but it is not getting the route if it is manually typed into the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review of my code and stackoverflow browsing, I came with a solution but I'm uncertain with the possible security. If you have a better approach, please share.

Route:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

AuthGuard:

```
const currentRoute = route.url[0].path;
let isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();

if (isAuth) {
  if (currentRoute === 'login') {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
} else {
  if (currentRoute === 'login') {
    isAuth = true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
return isAuth;
```

The `isAuth` returns boolean if authenticated or not and here in AuthGuard I used `let` and changed the value to `true`.